# Why can I not open runnable .jar files when I use JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I can not open runnable .jar files when I used JaxaFX. I double-click the file and just nothing happens. If I export a runnable .jar with a GUI I created in swing it opens normally. 
I tried opening my .jar on another pc and I had the same problem.
For creating the GUI I used Scene Builder. But I also tested just exporting a simple pane without the implementation of Scene Builder. Same result.

I have these versions of Java JDK (12.0.1), Java SE (8 update 211) and Java JRE (8 update 211) installed.

I tried all three options when exporting: "Extract required libraries...", "Package required libraries..." and "Copy required libraries...". None of them worked.
I use Eclipse. When creating a "JaxaFX project" it also creates a file called "build.fxbuild" inside the project folder. I tried creating a .jar with that. But it shows that "The project is attached to a JRE only so ant would be started with a JRE which does not have a compiler. Would you like to proceed and select a JDK?". If I clicked "yes" it showed a list but no entry in it for me to select. 
Below I post the code of my "main".

```java
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyScene.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The only solution for me was to create a .bat file. Inside it I put a command that I had seen in a tutorial somewhere:"java -jar 'name of that file'.jar". If I open that one everything works as it should.

Comment: Are JAR files associated with `java` on your computer?

Comment: Currently they are associated with "Java (TM) Platform SE binary". Is this the right one?

Comment: You have both Java 8 and Java 12 on your computer; which version is it associated with? Note that JavaFX was included in Java 8 (Oracle) but is not included in Java 11+. You say it works from the command line (i.e. `java -jar ...`), but the version of Java found on the PATH might not be the same one you associated `.jar` files with.

Comment: I just tried opening the .jar file with "D:/programs/Java/jre1.8.0_211/bin/java.exe".
In programs/Java were to more folders, JDK 8 and 12. I tried opening the .jar with the .exe inside these folders as well but it did not work.